# React Native - How to Application X open Application Y if Application Y has been installed

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want My Application (say Application X) want to open Application Y, if Application Y installed. And work in Android and iOS (open App Store / Play store if Application Y not installed)

What i have done :

```
Linking.openURL(applicationStoreURL);
```

> The code above success open Play Store/App Store of Application Y, but
>   actually the application Y has been installed so i want to direct open
>   to Application Y from Application X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Library

> "Easily deep link to other apps in React Native. If the app isn't installed on the user's phone, open the App Store or Play Store link instead."

https://github.com/FiberJW/react-native-app-link

```
npm i -S react-native-app-link


import AppLink from 'react-native-app-link';

AppLink.maybeOpenURL(url, { appName, appStoreId, appStoreLocale, playStoreId }).then(() => {
  // do stuff
})
.catch((err) => {
  // handle error
});

AppLink.openInStore({ appName, appStoreId, appStoreLocale, playStoreId }).then(() => {
  // do stuff
})
.catch((err) => {
  // handle error
});
```